# Convert signal strength to dbm

Tags: mobile-network, network-signal

I've got this app which shows network signal strength as a positive integer value btw 5 and 35. Another app uses negative integers like -99dbm.

Is there a way to convert the positive values (unit unknown) to dbm?

Comment: are you sure about the 5..35 range? the other popular unit for signal strength is `ASU` (Arbitrary Strength Unit) and its range for GSM networks is 0..31

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. The values were given in steps of five e.g 0-5, 6-10... Found the formula: dBm = 2 × ASU - 113, ASU in the range of
0..31 and 99 (for not known or not
detectable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dBm = (2 × ASU) - 113
ASU in the range of 0-31 and 99 (for not known or not
detectable).